# TomEE and ActiveMQ with Websockets

Tags: websocket, activemq-classic, stomp, apache-tomee, tomee-7

So TomEE 7.0.3 includes ActiveMQ 5.14.3.

ActiveMQ includes a websockets w/ STOMP (or mqtt) server. I have a javascript site that I need to hook into ActiveMQ, which is easy with STOMP.

So far, here's what I've done:

- Edited `\TomEE\conf\tomee.xml` to add the correct resource adapters
- Copied `activemq-stomp-5.14.3.jar`, `activemq-http-5.14.3.jar`, and `jetty-all-9.2.13.v20150730.jar` from ActiveMQ 5.14.3 to `\TomEE\lib\`
- Edited `\TomEE\conf\catalina.properties` to allow the Jetty jar, as that's required.

Problem: I'm getting `org.catalina.LifecycelException`s, some caused by `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket....` This plays out in that TomEE can no longer host sites (e.g. localhost:8080) but now it *does* accept STOMP over Websockets connecting to ActiveMQ. I'm 100% sure the problem is Jetty, but removing it breaks STOMP and Websockets.

Is there any way to fix this problem in configuration, or will I have to write my own Websockets -> STOMP -> ActiveMQ translator?

Comment: Why not just use the WebSocket implementation present in Tomcat?

Comment: How do you get ActiveMQ to use Tomcat's WebSocket implementation instead of Jetty?

Comment: You can't at the moment, AMQ only supports ws transport based on jetty (https://github.com/apache/activemq/blob/master/activemq-http/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/transport/ws/WSTransportServer.java)